# I want to remove what is not matched with patterns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

`df_2 = df_1[~df_1['MUTATION_CDS'].astype(str).str.contains('\?|del')]`

`df_3 = df_2[~df_2['MUTATION_CDS'].astype(str).str.contains('dup')]`

I used these two lines to delete the values in the MUTATION_CDS column.

but it is much easier to use a pattern. my pattern is '()>()' 
capital alphabet A,T,G,C can come in () like 'G>C', 'A>T'
I want to only leave the values which have this pattern in the 'MUTATION_CDS' column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? I don't know what other strings might pop up in `'MUTATION_CDS'`. Basically you want a pattern [A or T or G or C] followed by ">" then same pattern again.

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'MUTATION_CDS':['A>C','C>G','G>T','T>A','AAdel','BBBdup','Whatever'
    ...: ]})
df_1[df_1['MUTATION_CDS'].astype(str).str.contains("[ATGC]>[ATGC]")]
```